# Azure DevOps Release - Failed to Fetch App Service 'ABC' publishing credentials - 400 Bad Request

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to deploy my release on Azure Node.js Web App. When I am initiating a deploy of the release, I get this error:

> Error: Failed to fetch App Service 'ABC'
>   publishing credentials. Error: Could not fetch access token for
>   Managed Service Principal. Please configure Managed Service Identity
>   (MSI) for virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status
>   code: 400, status message: Bad Request

I have an organization's azure Visual studio Professional subscription. I am using Service connection of type Managed Service Identity (MSI) as I do not have permission to create Managed Service Principal. I have enabled System assigned Identity on a web app in Azure. My web app is Node.js on Linux. The deployment task is running with Hosted Agent (Ubuntu 1604).

I am new to Azure and DevOps so I might have missed trivial details. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Service connection of type MSI only work for self-hosted agent (=your custom VM agent). If you're using Hosted agent, you need to create a service principal that have access (contributor) to your webapp

Comment: @Thomas, I created a self hosted Linux agent on a VM and configured my Build and Release pipeline to use the same. Build works fine but Release shows the same error (mentioned in question) even now.